# Can you compare tables with mysql using levenshtein or similar function?

Tags: mysql, levenshtein-distance

I have two tables with some company names from different sources I would like to compare/map.

Given the different sources it is possible in some cases there might be different naming protocols e.g. one might use ", LLC" the other "LLC," some might use "inc.", some might abbreviate part of the name, etc.

Is there a way to compare using some sort of 'similar()' function instead of using "=" or `like`?  I was thinking of perhaps making a new table with TableA|TableB|Match% and then I can keep 100% and verify the rest.

Comment: Yes. UDF's have been constructed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are some built in functions, such as `SOUNDEX()`, for [levenshtein use a custom function](http://openquery.com.au/blog/levenshtein-mysql-stored-function).

You can compare the different tables by using the system database and table 'SELECT * FROM information_scheme.COLUMNS".